# Is this a proper quicksort algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, quick-sort

```
import random

def qsort(qslist):

    small = []
    big = []

    if (len(qslist) < 2):
        return qslist

    elif (len(qslist) > 1):

        pivot = qslist[int(random.randrange(len(qslist)))]

        for x in range(len(qslist)):
            if qslist[x] <= pivot:
                small.append(qslist[x])
            else:
                big.append(qslist[x])
        if(len(big) == 0):
            big.append(pivot)
            small.remove(pivot)

return qsort(small) + qsort(big)

qslist = [9,1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5]
print(qsort(qslist))
```

Please give me advice while picking up Python.  I'm trying to do so while at the same time doing some basic algorithms.

1. Have I understood how the quicksort algorithm work?
2. Please give me some general feedback on the Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments:

- Write docstrings to document code
- Use `if`/`else` instead of `if`/`elif` if possible
- Use list comprehensions
- Use `random.choice` to get a random element from a non-empty sequence

The code in the original questions with the suggested improvements would be as follows:

```
import random

def qsort(qslist):
    """"Quicksort implementation."""
    if len(qslist) < 2:
        return qslist

    pivot = random.choice(qslist)
    small = [x for x in qslist if x < pivot]
    equal = [x for x in qslist if x == pivot]
    big = [x for x in qslist if x > pivot]

    return qsort(small) + equal + qsort(big)

qslist = [9,1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5]
print(qsort(qslist))
```

Edit: If you prefer to avoid traversing the array three times, a partition
function to do that very similar to the one in the original question would be:

```
def partition(qslist):
    """Partition array using a pivot value."""
    small = []
    equal = []
    big = []

    pivot = random.choice(qslist)
    for x in qslist:
        if x < pivot:
            small.append(x)
        elif x == pivot:
            equal.append(x)
        else:
            big.append(x)

    return small, equal, big
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, but i wonder if your code works if the list contains several of the "same" items, it dosent seem todo. Chane the list to contain several "1" to se what i mean.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The code indeed failed in the case of repeated values, I've updated it to take that into account.

Comment: Great, i need to do a bit more of list compehensions! :)

Comment: Note that I used list comprehensions for readability, but you can still define your own partition function to do just one pass over `qsist` which would be more efficient.

Comment: Yeah, i prefer only to traverse one time :)

Comment: @jcollado note that as the `if` contains a `return`, you can leave out the `else` entirely - saves a level of nesting in the rest of the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're absolutely right. I've updated the response following your advice. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you suggest if/else over if/elif/else?

Comment: @miR What I suggest is `if`/`else` over `if`/`elif` when the condition in the `elif` is exclusive and, hence, not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @jcollado, now i look back at the OP's code I understand.  New'ish to Python so I ask questions.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

A few comments, not so much about the algorithm as it has be done pretty well already but more about the code itself :

- your `return` does not seem properly indented.
- you should put your test (or basically any code actually doing something) behind a [main guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578308/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-main-method-in-python).
- there is no point in checking if the length is bigger than 1 after you've checked that it is not smaller than 2. If you really want to, you can add an `assert`.
- you can (and should) define `big` and `small` as late as possible : we will only need them in the `else` case, this is where it belongs.
- the way you loop over the list is not pythonic at all. You should see the `for` loop as a for-each loop and use it as such. It makes things easier to read/write, it is shorter, it is more efficient and it will be easier to re-use if you have to work on different iterables.
- you could put your return in the `else` block or you could get rid of the `else` block alltogether as your return in the `then` block.

After taking into account these simple comments, here is what I have :

```
import random

def qsort(qslist):

    if len(qslist) < 2:
        return qslist

    assert len(qslist) > 1
    pivot = random.choice(qslist) 

    small = []
    big = []

    for x in qslist:
        if x <= pivot:
            small.append(x)
        else:
            big.append(x)
    if len(big) == 0:
        big.append(pivot)
        small.remove(pivot)

    return qsort(small) + qsort(big)

def main():
    """Main function"""
    print("Hello, world!")
    qslist = [9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5] * 200
    print(qsort(qslist))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the algorithm looks like quicksort.

There are only two things I would have done differently:

1. Why do you randomly generate a number within the range of the list to pick the corresponding element?  Just randomly pick an element from the list:

   ```
   pivot = random.choice(qslist)
   ```
2. Why do you generate sequential indices to pick all elements of your list?  Just sequentially pick all elements: `for value in qslist: ...`